# Creating large .xls with SXSSF

Tags: java, excel, xls, xlsx, jxls

I've got problem with exporting large .xls with SXSSF, saying large I mean 27 cols x 100 000 rows. Excel file is return on endpoint request. I've limited amount of rows - it can be 3x larger.

I'm using template engine for inserting data.

**Original code**

```
public StreamingOutput createStreamedExcelReport(Map<String, Object> params, String templateName, String[] columnsToHide) throws Exception {
        try(InputStream is = ReportGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream(templateName)) {
            assert is != null;
            final Transformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is);
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            Context context = new PoiContext();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                context.putVar(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet1!A1"), context);
            xlsArea.processFormulas();
            return new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                    ((PoiTransformer) transformer).getWorkbook().write(out);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

**SXSSF**

```
public StreamingOutput createStreamedExcelReport(Map<String, Object> params, String templateName, String[] columnsToHide) throws Exception {
        try(InputStream is = ReportGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream(templateName)) {
            assert is != null;
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
            final PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createSxssfTransformer(workbook);
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            Context context = new PoiContext();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                context.putVar(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet1!A1"), context);
            xlsArea.processFormulas();
            return new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                    transformer.getWorkbook().write(out);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Export was running for 7 mins and I stopped server - it was too long. Acceptable time would be something like 1 min (max. 2 min). Most of that time CPU usage was about 60-80% and memory usage was constant. I tried also exporting 40 rows - it took something like 10 sec.

Maybe my function needs to be optimized.

Additional problem is that I'm inserting functions. In original code functions are replaced with values. In SXSSF version they are not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to disable formulas processing at this point because the formulas support for SXSSF version is limited and the memory consumption can be too high. The formulas support may be improved in the future JXLS releases.

So just remove `xlsArea.processFormulas()` call and add

`context.getConfig().setIsFormulaProcessingRequired(false);`

to disable tracking of cell references (as shown in [Jxls doc](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/formulas.html)) and see if it works.

Also please note that the template and the final report are expected to be in .xlsx format if you use SXSSF.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. It works without formula processing, but it's still slower than non SXSSF version.

Comment: Have you played with Window Size option for SXSSF? Does it have an effect on the performance? My understanding is that the overall performance of SXSSF vs non-SXSSF may be not better. But the real benefit is an elimination of memory restrictions.

Comment: In this case, memory restrictions are not the problem. 3000 rows will export ~1min and I need to handle much more. Data set will grow so perfomance boost is needed. Any other solutions? Maybe some script in other language?

Comment: The more memory you use the more time your process will execute (don't forget about GC pauses). So if you expect your data set to grow I do not see any other options except using SXSSF and optimizing its performance. You can try to implement simple example using plain POI SXSSF and if you still have a performance problem you should ask for support at Apache POI forums